# Why can we instantiate a stack but not a queue?

Tags: java, stack, queue

Why I can instantiate a stack like this:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
```

But can't instantiate a queue like this:

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<>();
```

Is that because queue is a interface while `stack is a object`?
If so, why we say that everything in java is an object?

Comment: `Queue<Integer> myQueue = new LinkedList<>();`

Answer (score 4):

**A Queue is an interface, meaning we cannot construct a Queue directly.**

We can create object using implementing classes,  implements the Queue interface, like one of the following: `AbstractQueue`, `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, `DelayQueue`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `LinkedList`, `PriorityBlockingQueue`, `PriorityQueue`, or `SynchronousQueue`.

**Stack is the class** and can be instantiated directly.

This is by design and with `Queue`, lot more options are there using implementing classes.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `Queue` is an `interface`. You can only instantiate (non-abstract) classes. Nevertheless, the resulting instance is still a `Queue`.

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Same with `List`

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

`Stack` on the other hand is a class, like `Vector` (from which it inherits)  or `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

> If so, why we say that everything in java is an object?

We should probably not be saying that (seeing that there also non-objects like `int`), but more to your point, any instance of `Queue` (which has to be an instance of something like `LinkedList` as well) is an `Object` (as well as a `Collection` and an `Iterable`).

`Object` is the root of all object types in Java. So in that sense, everything is an `Object` in Java (some other languages do not have a common root type for all objects).

Answer (score 0):

The Queue, being interface can't be implemented. It has other implementations that you can use.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList()<Integer>;
```

Visit this for more info about classes that implement the queue interface:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html